# Variable substitutions in docker-compose in Azure Docker Web app

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have a docker-compose file that contains a secret for my database.

```
port: 4466
managementApiSecret: ${DB_SECRET}
```

So I would like to use Docker-Compose's Variable Substitution (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) to be able to provide my secrets through an environment variable instead of my yaml file.

Is this at all possible using the "Application Settings" variables on my Azure Linux Docker Instance?

It doesn't seem to work for me, I've tried both ${VAR} and $VAR syntax and neither worked. I also tried with secrets that only contain alphanumerics and numbers.

Thanks in advance. 
Frank

Comment: Even better would be if I could get it from my Azure key vault, somehow.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this at all in Azure Web app for Containers? i'm looking to add versioning to the compose file as per the example given by the docker docuentation - but it appears this is not supported. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables that you need to start the container (for example: you want to include build number in container name) can be added to .env file in same directory as the docker-compose.yml file.

sample .env file:

`DB_SECRET=foo`

run: `docker-compose config`  and verify that the variable has been substituted with the value you have in .env file

Also, I recommend using `managementApiSecret:"${DB_SECRET}"` (note the quotes around the variable) in your docker-compose.yml file

There might be azure specific way to share secrets but I didn't try that yet.

If you want to pass in environment variables that the container needs, then https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file is what you want. Those environment vars will become part of environment inside docker container.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'll see if I can somehow get to the folder containing the yaml file on the deployment, (so I can try with a .env file) and get back to you.